# ¿Como puedo generar un .exe con todos los recursos de manera interna? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, compilar, exe

tengo un proyecto que estoy haciendo en visual studio, con vb.net, el detalle es que utilizo archivos como imágenes, audios o exenciones ejecutables en .exe que llamo por Process.

Mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo meter todo eso de manera interna en el .exe, sin importar el tamaño del archivo .exe resultante?¿Es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, sí es posible.
Si abres la ventana de propiedades del proyecto (botón derecho sobre el proyecto en el Explorador de Soluciones y seleccionar la opción "Propiedades...") verás que en el menú de la izquierda tienes la opción "Recursos", esta opción te permite añadir al ejecutable diferentes recursos como textos, imágenes o cualquier tipo de archivo:

[image: Recursos del proyecto]

Aquí tienes información más detallada de cómo hacerlo:

[Cómo incrustar y tener acceso a recursos mediante Visual Basic .NET o Visual Basic 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/319291/how-to-embed-and-access-resources-by-using-visual-basic--net-or-visual)

Comment: Una ultima cosa. Acabo de añadir el archivo ffmpeg.exe, pero al ejecutar un If File.Exists("\Resources\ffmpeg.exe") Then me devuelve que no existe. ¿Como acceso a ellos?

Comment: El archivo no va a existir en ninguna ruta, el contenido del archivo está dentro del exe pero no existe como archivo. En el link que te incluyo en la respuesta tienes un ejemplo de cómo acceder a estos recursos.

Comment: Me revise toda la pagina sin embargo habla en contextos de imágenes o texto, pero no de archivos exe.

        Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("Aqui la ruta de ffmpeg")
...

Comment: El proceso para leer un archivo es el mismo sea imagen o exe. El problema es que lo que obtendrás es el contenido del archivo en memoria. Si necesitas acceder a él a través de una ruta deberás guardar el contenido en un archivo de disco o incluir el archivo como un archivo adicional de tu aplicación.

Comment: No tienes que verificar si existe de esa manera, una vez que lo importaste a tus recursos lo puedes llamar asi: My.Resources. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-resources-object